# mplayer text overlays on a video playback

Tags: mplayer

I'm trying to find out how to overlay a video with text while it's playing (not encoded into the video). I need to overlay multiple text (prices) over a video showing products. The prices change often which is the reason for wanting to do price (text) overlay as it plays.
I've done a tonne of Google searches but nothing came up. I'm sure this is a pretty common request, and mplayer is capable of it, I just don't know how to do it. Are you able to help me with this please?
Please provide a reasonably detailed response so I don't misunderstand. TIA.